# Blank page after successful form submit - Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am using below function to add an item to cart (which right now is an array, that will be stored in session later). Every thing is working fine only problem is that when i click "**Add+**" button, it stores all the values in the array but gives a blank page after.

**My Controller**

```
if($action == 'Add+') {
    if($this->session->userdata('cart')== ''){
        $image=$this->input->post('hidden_image');
        $name= $this->input->post('hidden_name');
        $price= $this->input->post('hidden_price');
        $cat= $this->input->post('hidden_cat');
        $id= $this->input->post('hidden_id');
        $product = array("name"=>$name, "price"=>$price, "id"=>$id, "image" => $image,"cat"=>$cat);
        $item= array("0"=>$product);
        $this->session->set_userdata('cart',$item);

    }
    else{
        $count= count($this->session->userdata('cart'));
        $name= $this->input->post('hidden_name');
        $price= $this->input->post('hidden_price');
        $id= $this->input->post('hidden_id');
        $image=$this->input->post('hidden_image');
        $cat= $this->input->post('hidden_cat');
        $product = array("name"=>$name, "price"=>$price, "id"=>$id, "image" => $image,"cat"=>$cat);
        $item= array($count=>$product);
        $data = $this->session->userdata('cart');
        $_SESSION["cart"][$count] = $product;
    }
}
if($action == 'View') {
    $image=$this->input->post('hidden_image');
    $name= $this->input->post('hidden_name');
    $price= $this->input->post('hidden_price');
    $id= $this->input->post('hidden_id');
    $cat= $this->input->post('hidden_cat');
    $product = array("name"=>$name, "price"=>$price, "id"=>$id, "image" => $image,"cat"=>$cat);
    $this->load->view('product_head');
    $this->load->view('header',$product);
    $this->load->view('product',$product);
}
```

**My View**

```
 <?php $data= array ('id'=>'productform');
                     echo form_open_multipart('loader/product',$data);
                                $data = array(
                                'type'          => 'hidden',
                                'name'          => 'hidden_cat',
                                'value' => $row->category);
                                $val = set_value('hidden_cat');
                                echo form_input($data, $val);


                                $data = array(
                                'type'          => 'hidden',
                                'name'          => 'hidden_name',
                                'value' => $row->name
                                    );
                                $val = set_value('hidden_name');
                                echo form_input($data, $val);


                                $data = array(
                                    'type'          => 'hidden',
                                    'name'          => 'hidden_image',
                                    'value' => $row->image
                                        );
                                    $val = set_value('hidden_image');
                                    echo form_input($data, $val);


                                $data = array(
                                    'type'          => 'hidden',
                                    'name'          => 'hidden_id',
                                    'value' => $row->id
                                        );
                                    $val = set_value('hidden_id');
                                    echo form_input($data, $val);


                                $data = array(
                                'type'          => 'hidden',
                                'name'          => 'hidden_price',
                                'value' => $row->price
                                    );
                                $val = set_value('hidden_price');
                                echo form_input($data, $val);


                                $data = array(
                                'name' => 'action',
                                'style'         => ' background-color: #4CAF50; border: none;',
                                'value'      => 'View'
                                 );
                                echo form_submit($data);    


                                $data = array(
                                'name' => 'action',
                                'style'         => ' background-color: #4CAF50; border: none;',
                                'id' => 'addbtn'
                                    );
                                echo form_submit($data);

                                echo form_close(); 
                                ?>
```

what I want is that after successful form submit it stay on same page at same place because there are many pages that have these hidden forms for every product.

Comment: Is there any code after if condition?

Comment: Also, there is a syntax error after `if($this->session->userdata('cart')== ''){` closing `}` is missing. This may be the reason you are getting blank page.

Comment: You probably want to look into using Ajax if you want to stay on the same page.

Comment: `print_r($this->session->userdata('cart'));exit;` use this after `if($action == 'Add+') {` and share the result

Comment: Code is working fine, i didnt post whole function before that is why ' { ' was missing,

Comment: how are you getting `$action` value after form submit?

Comment: form has 2 submit buttons, trigger some part of same function in the controller,i am getting value of  `$action` with post

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? A "blank page" might indicate that an error occured, but has not been delivered all the way to the browser

Comment: As i already told there is not any kind of error, i just want to trigger the function in my controller without any kind of page redirect or refresh.

Comment: you see the blank page because you didn't enable error reporting. enable error reporting from index.php file and see the error

Comment: @AbdulManan there re no errors, it shows blank page because i am not redirecting any where or loading a view, that is because i want to stay on the same page.

Comment: @HamzaAnsari as per your code for view there is no value set for `add` button. You have to add one more array element as `value='Add+'`.